# Соединение нескольких строк в одну

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возникла такая проблема, что мне нужно соединить три строчки SurnameTeacher, FirstnameTeacher и PatronymicTeacher из таблицы Teacher в одну строчку ID_Teacher в таблице ListOfTests. Прикрепляю скриншоты, для лучшего понимания. Как это реализовать? Сделать подобное нужно через запрос

[image: Таблица Teacher]

[image: Таблица ListOfTests]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Задавая вопрос, вам необходимо предоставить [минимальный воспроизводимый пример] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Заполнение DDL и выборочных данных, т. е. таблицы CREATE плюс операторы INSERT T-SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т. е. логика и ваш код пытающийся реализовать ее в T-SQL.
(3) Желаемый результат, основанный на примерных данных в # 1 выше.
(4) Ваша версия SQL Server (SELECT @@version;).
Все в рамках вопроса как текст, без картинок.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SurnameTeacher, FirstnameTeacher, PatronymicTeacher) AS ID_Teacher FROM Teacher;
```

Это если верно понимать то что Вы хотите )